# Pillow program to do watermark

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I've done a python script using Pillow to automatically watermark the images on one folder and save the watermarked image to other folder. The program is made but I noticed that the new photos come with some more MB like the original one is 10Mb and the watermarked is 25Mb and the program also takes a lot of time to run. I don't know what to do in order to improve it.

Here's the code

```
from PIL import Image
import os
#foreground = Image.open("watermark.png").convert('RGBA')
#background = Image.open("FotosAntes\\21231891_468587483512430_7958322633319552407_n.jpg").convert('RGBA')
#
#maxsize = (300,300)
#foreground.thumbnail(maxsize, Image.ANTIALIAS)
#
#background.paste(foreground, (670, 500), foreground)
#background.convert('P', palette=Image.ADAPTIVE, colors=256)
#background.save("FotosDepois\\Foto1.png", "PNG")
#
#background.show()

original_path = ("FotosAntes")
destination_path = ("FotosDepois")
#maxsize = (500,500)
foreground = Image.open("arroz.png").convert('RGBA')
#foreground.thumbnail(maxsize, Image.ANTIALIAS)

for (dirName, subDirs, fileNames) in os.walk(original_path):
    for i in fileNames:
        file_name_op = (os.path.splitext(i)[0])
        background = Image.open(os.path.join(dirName, i)).convert('RGBA')
        background.paste(foreground, (4550, 2850), foreground)
        background.convert('P', palette=Image.ADAPTIVE, colors=256)
        outfile = os.path.split
        background.save("FotosDepois\\" + file_name_op + ".png")
        print("Foto complete")
```

The first comments was the version of my program that I tested to do only one photo and then I created the final program (the loop).

Comment: If you save a JPEG as a PNG, it's going to inflate in size significantly.

Comment: Yeah I know but I can't save it to JPG, It is not possibly cause it's impossible to save RGB to JPG